# Control not reaching to .js function

Tags: javascript, html

In my following code, I am calling function "Make Request" that is located in a separate .js file. But the control is not reaching to this function. I have also added the link to the related file.

```
<link rel="section" href="../Lib/ajaxhandler.js" type="text/javascript">

<td oncontrolselect="MakeRequest('inCategory','SELECT * FROM electioncategorymaster', 'ecid', 'ecname');">
    <select id="inCategory" name="inCategory" class="entryFormInputBoxColor">

    </select>
</td>
```

I want to make a call to the MakeRequest function when page is rendered. On which event I must call the function?

Comment: You really wanna send SQL queries to a gateway? Your database is gone be flat and hacked in a second. ;-)

Comment: @Philippe: Thanks for the suggestion. At present I am testing dynamically filling the DropDown. Will definitely take this into concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link to the script is wrong. The `link` tag is useful for e.g. stylesheets.

Your script tag should be like this:

```
<script src="../Lib/ajaxhandler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, you may want to catch the `oncontrolselect` event of the combo box instead of the `td`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
<script src="../Lib/ajaxhandler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<td>
    <select id="inCategory" name="inCategory" class="entryFormInputBoxColor" 
            onChange="MakeRequest('inCategory','SELECT * FROM electioncategorymaster', 'ecid', 'ecname');">

    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: @Ei: It's not working well on Change, but works well on MouseAbove.